# Rails - Render an opaque/transparent navbar on application layout on top of every(Yield) page content

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-5

Can someone please help me?
I'm making a website using Rails 5.2.0(i'm new to Rails). My problem is that my navbar is transparent(as the image bellow show - this is a Figma prototype) and i'm having difficulties to render it on the views/layouts/application.html.erb with the effect that i want it to reproduce.

[This is the prototype i want to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaXQI.jpg).
I would like that my navbar appears on top of the pages content(the pages we "Yield" on the layout". Ex: in the home page i want the opaque/transparent navbar to appear on top of my banner, like an overlay effect, the way it shows on  my prototype above.

For the moment, the way my code is, the navbar does not overlay my banner in the home page, it appears before the homepage content starts(on top), which is the normal behaviour when we render a partial on the application layout on top of the "Yield")

This is my homepage html code:

```html
<div class="banner">
 
 <div>
  <h1><span class="title-bold">WELCOME TO</span> <span class="title-light">M3 VILLAGE</span></h1>
  <h3>XAI-XAI | MOZAMBIQUE</h3>
  <%= link_to "ACCOMMODATION", "https://www.lewagon.com/", class: "btn-banner " %>
  <%= link_to "RESTAURANT & PUB", "https://www.lewagon.com/", class: "btn-banner " %>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-aboutus">
 <div class="container">
  <h4>About us</h4>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupida</p> 
 </div>

</div>
<div class="wrapper-rooms">
 <div class="container">
  <h4>Rooms</h4>
  <p>Clean, confortable and well equiped rooms, that match your needs!</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my navbar code:

```css
.navbar-mini{
background: #181818;
// width: 1440px;
height: 50px ;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: lighter;


}
.nav-flexbox{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
padding: 14px;
opacity: 0.8;
}
.nav-flexbox p{
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-family: Open Sans;
font-size: 13px;

}
.nav-icons  a{
color: #FFFFFF;
opacity: 0.8;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-icons  i{
position: relative;
    left: -24px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar-large{
 height: 120px;
   background-color: black;
   opacity: .4;
   // position: fixed;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-mini">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="nav-flexbox">
   <p>Rua do Miau Miau, Xai-Xai |hello@m3village.com</p>
   <div class="nav-icons">
    <%= link_to "#" do %>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> 
    <% end %> 
    <%= link_to "Login", "#" %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar-large">

</div>
```

How do i manage to make my navbar to appear on every page, but at the same time overlay the content of the pages?

Thank you in advance for your help.